set width for org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart
I have a class extending ViewPart
public class LicenseWarningView extends ViewPart {
...
}

How can I set the fixed width for this ViewPart?

Duplicate or similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/977528/6505250 (see also Javadoc of org.eclipse.ui.IViewPart).

This question is similar to: How do I programmatically resize an eclipse ViewPart?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
